# How can I get make element visible by hovering other element

Tags: css

I need to use CSS only solution (NO Jquery) to show a FontAwsome icon (`<i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success hidearrowbounce'></i>`)  when hovering another element, but at the moment, eventhough I have tried to hide it initially with `.hidearrowbounce` it has the opposite effect that it shows on load but dissapear on hover .. how can I make it hide initially and show when hovering over?

**My Code:**

```css
.hidearrowbounce {
  display: none;
}

.tr_user_done:hover {
  background: #e9ecef;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tr_user_done:hover .TextSpanDone:hover {
  color: #28a745;
}

.tr_user_done:hover .TextSpanDone:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tr_user_done:hover .TextSpanDone:hover:after + .hidearrowbounce {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  color: #28a745;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.arrowbounce {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<table>
  <tr class="tr_user_done hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='#';">
    <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
    <td>
      <div class="TextSpanDone" data-hover="TEXT ON HOVER" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
        <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Initial text</b><i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success hidearrowbounce'></i>
          <DIV>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which element is "another element", can you please specify?

Comment: Let me guess, you want to show a green arrow when user hover over a table row, right?

Comment: @hussain.codes The other hovering element that should trigger icon visibility is `tr_user_done:hover .TextSpanDone:hover:after` to where I have added the `+ .hidearrowbounce `

Comment: @hussain.codes yes, correct

Comment: Your own CSS is getting superceded by Fontawesome's CSS which you should move to the head element of your code, followed by your own styles so they take precedence. Also remember to display: inline-block your arrow when you want it to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially arrow visibility is set to `hidden` but you hover over table row arrow visibility changes from `hidden` to `visibile`.

```css
.arrowbounce{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.tr_user_done:hover {
  background: #e9ecef;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tr_user_done:hover .arrowbounce,
.TextSpanDone:hover .arrowbounce
{
  visibility:visible;
}

.tr_user_done:hover .TextSpanDone:hover {
  color: #28a745;
}




.arrowbounce {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}
.tr_user_done:hover .TextSpanDone:hover:after + .hidearrowbounce {
   visibility: visible;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100% !important;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   content: attr(data-hover);
  color: #28a745;
  vertical-align: top;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<table>
  <tr class="tr_user_done hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='#';">
    <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
    <td>
      <div class="TextSpanDone" data-hover="TEXT ON HOVER" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
        <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Initial text</b><i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success '></i>
          <DIV>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: great .. but my `content: attr(data-hover);` does not work .. I can see that it in my snippet did not eigher, but works in my code .. strange

Comment: Sorry, i think i removed that part of css accidentally. let me add that back. 1 min

Comment: I have added whatever css i previously removed, i don't see any visual difference though.

Comment: I have just made a Fiddle where the hover text is displayed, but the icon acts really weird : https://jsfiddle.net/skolbaek/ho6mxfr9/7/

Comment: problem was to show an arrow on table row hover, which i think is working fine now. please explain what do you mean by arrow acting weird.

Comment: Try look at version 8 now (https://jsfiddle.net/skolbaek/ho6mxfr9/8/) .. The arrow is vissible at all time at the left, when hovering it places inside the TR where it should be, but at the left and not the right

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working from the help by @hussain.codes, and here is the finished code:

```css
.arrowbounce {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tr_user_tasks_done:hover .TaskTextSpanITDone:hover {
  color: #28a745;
}

.tr_user_tasks_done:hover .TaskTextSpanITDone:hover {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tr_user_tasks_done:hover .TaskTextSpanITDone:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  color: #28a745;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.tr_user_tasks_done:hover {
  background: #e9ecef;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tr_user_tasks_done:hover .arrowbounce,
.tr_user_tasks_done:hover .arrowbounce {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: attr(data-hover);
  color: #28a745;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.arrowbounce {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 4px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-15px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<center>
  <table>
    <tr class="tr_user_tasks_done hand_user_tasks" onclick="window.location='#">
      <td align="center" style="width: 30px;"><i class="fas fa-check text-success"></i></td>
      <td>
        <div class="TaskTextSpanITDone" data-hover="Hover text" style="width: 400px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
          <font style="font-size: 13px;"><b>Initial text</b></font>
          <i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left fa-lg arrowbounce text-success'></i>
          <DIV>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
```